# How to open hyperlink in new window while using .rdlc XML file?

Tags: xml, hyperlink, action, reporting, rdlc

For example:

```
<Action>
<Hyperlink>=www.google.com</Hyperlink>
</Action>
```

These code open the link in same page or tag. My query is to open it in a separate window or tab?

Comment: Check in below link hope you will get answer: https://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/Contents/Item/Display/87

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: An answer came in below that suggested [this link](https://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/Contents/Item/Display/87). It is likely to be deleted from answers for being link-only, so I'm adding it to the comments.